# ASP.NET Web API: service files not found by IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webserver, asp.net-core-webapi

I have deployed a service, which is based on an ASP .NET WEB API (using .NET Core 7.0) to IIS. The application seems to work and does find the config file (If it is configured wrong, errors will be thrown).

If I try to access the application (Browse Application (port 80)), the page remains blank. If I reload it with dev tools open, a 404 status code gets shown.

[image]

**Web.config:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding>
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <modules>
                <add name="UriCacheModule" />
                <add name="FileCacheModule" />
                <add name="TokenCacheModule" />
                <add name="RequestMonitorModule" />
                <add name="ManagedEngineV4.0_32bit" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />
                <add name="ManagedEngineV4.0_64bit" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
        <!--<remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />-->
      </modules>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\REST_TestService.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
      <!--<aspNetCore processPath=".\REST_TestService.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />-->
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: c65c47fd-472a-4879-8bf7-d50afe3e4525-->
```

I use IIS Web Deploy with Visual Studio 2022 to publish the service. In addition I tried to copy the files over after publishing it to a directory with the same result.

- I checked permissions on the file system
- I enabled directory browsing
- I disabled request filtering
- I tried using the server name and the IP address instead of localhost
- I checked the IIS logs, but could not find any helpful information (It is not writing anything when calling the app)
- I checked the mapping of the physical path to the virtual directory
- I checked different settings within the web.config according to other stack overflow questions

As the config file is found, I assume that this is an issue with the config file. I tried lots of different settings, but nothing changed the behavior.

After running out of ideas, searching for a solution for multiple hours and trying lots of stuff, I have to raise this topic as a question and hope for a solution. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Try using FRT to view details about the 404 error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. This link provide the method to enable failed request tracing to capture the detailed error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis